# Does docker push base images that are already in docker hub?

Tags: docker

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./index.js .
EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

This results in an image that has a size of `920MB` but my actual project size is about `2.5MB` I guess that the rest is the `node:12` base image, which is alright.

However, when I try to push my image to Docker hub I need to upload several huge image layers.

Is this expected? shouldn't docker just use the base node image that is available in the docker hub and not upload it again from my computer?

Comment: I seriously doubt that `RUN npm install` only results in a few Mb once all deps have been downloaded. As is your docker file creates at least 3 layers (corresponding to the `COPY` + `RUN` + `COPY` commands) on top of the `node:12` base image, the biggest probably being the one created by your install command. Check the size on you local dev.

Comment: @Zeitounator running this with `node:12-alpine` results in an image size of `91.6MB` which is easily uploaded local folder with `node_modules` is `2.5MB`, this is a simple express hello world app.

Comment: As @Zeitounator stated, the `npm install` commands adds a lot to your image.
If your goal is to ship the dependencies within the image, there's little you can do.
Another approach though would be to install dependencies at run time. Remove your `RUN npm install` line and change your CMD line to `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npm install && node index.js"]`. The container will be slower to start up, but much smaller. From there you can further improve : add a lockfile, use a volume to store node_modules, perform `npm install` in an entrypoint script, ...